# HTML My second tab will not change?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put tabs in my html site. The Log In tab is the way I want it to be. That it just says e-mail password log in! But the Sign Up tab will not change to what I put for the code. Does my code look right?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#log in">Log In</a></li>
<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="log in" class="tab-pane fade in active">
<br>
<form>
```

E-mail:
    
 
  Password:

```
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

<button type="button">Log In!</button> <br> <br>

</div>

<div id="sign up" class="tab-pane fade">
  <form action="/action_page.php">

  <form action="/action_page.php">
```

Username:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
```

E-mail:

```
<form>  Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="psw">

<br>

<p>By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our Terms and Privacy Policy</p> 

<button type="button">Sign Up!</button> </h2> </div> 

</form>
</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not know why this is displaying differently from my post. But okay

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues:

1. IDs [cannot contain spaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). Change "log in" to "login" and "sign up" to "signup".
2. There are several nested `<form>` tags. [Forms cannot contain forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form). I've removed them.
3. There is an errant `</h2>` tag. I removed it.
4. The `<form>` closes after it's containing `<div>` closes. I switched the closing tags.
5. A closing `</p>` tag seems to be intended as a closing `</div>` tag.

I think this might be closer to what you're going for:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#login">Log In</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#signup">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">

      <div id="login" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <form>
          E-mail:<br>
          <input type="text" name="e-mail"><br><br>
          Password:<br>
          <input type="password" name="psw"><br><br>
          &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <button type="button">Log In!</button><br><br>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="signup" class="tab-pane fade">
        <form action="/action_page.php">
          Username:<br>
          <input type="text" name="Username"><br><br>
          E-mail:<br>
          <input type="email" name="e-mail"><br><br>
          Password:<br>
          <input type="password" name="psw"><br>
          <p>By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our Terms and Privacy Policy</p>
          <button type="button">Sign Up!</button>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

You might benefit from using an HTML validator.
[This one](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html) seems to show errors in a fairly clear way.